# Using wget to download files and folders from RawGit

Tags: android, bash, busybox

I want to retrieve files using wget, through RawGit.
The command I'm using:

```
wget raw.githubusercontent.com/DevBonBon/The_Thing/Finish-Tim-TheThing/system/bin/Tim
```

And it returns:

```
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (23.235.43.133:80)
wget: not an http or ftp url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DevBonBon
```

/The_Thing/Finish-Tim-TheThing/system/bin/Tim
I'm using busyboxes wget, as I want this to work on android. The command works fine on Linux, but always fails when using busybox. Is there a way around this or another command I could use?

Comment: I could add the GNU wget to android and use that instead, but that should be the last option to use.

Comment: looks like the wget embedded in busybox is not compiled with ssl

Comment: @njzk2 Well, that's dumb of them, Is there any other commands I could use to substitute wget?

Comment: either install the proper wget, or something else like curl, or serve your file on an http server that does not force the redirection to https.

Comment: Is there a way to download from raw.githubusercontent.com *without* using HTTPS, i.e. using some URL parameters or HTTP request headers which the raw.githubusercontent.com understands and prevents the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Android version of wget, made by [Jacob Hoffman-Andrews](https://github.com/jsha/android-wget)

Have a look a this page: https://jacob.hoffman-andrews.com/android/wget/

[Here](http://www.4shared.com/file/YVutQQXrba/wget-binary.html) is a download mirror of the binary.